# WPF - Relative transform on brush results in jagged lines

Tags: wpf, transform, brush, rotatetransform, drawingbrush

After applying a relative rotate transform (of 45 degrees) on a brush in WPF, I am left with extremely jagged lines. Has anyone else experienced this? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Still no idea what caused this, but I bypassed it by skewing an element inside the brush instead of transforming the brush itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this once again after the switch to VS2010. It worked fine..I love a good update!